# MySQL tabla de 2 campos, que solo se pueda repetir uno de los campos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, tablas, uml

tengo esta tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `etiquetas_en_mensajes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_mensaje` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_etiqueta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`id_etiqueta`,`id_mensaje`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Y con el `UNIQUE KEY` que cree queria lograr que el  que solo pudiera tener un mensaje solo una etiqueta del mismo tipo, me explico:

Pongo un ejemplo:

Creo un mensaje(id = 3) y le asigno la etiqueta #comedia (id = 45), pues en la BD se guarda algo como `('auto_increment',3,45)` ahora **una vez guardado** si yo intento volver a menter el mensaje con **id 3** con la etiqueta con **id 45** que me diga que no se puede. 
Pero con el **CONSTRAINT** que hice **NO** me deja meter dos mensaje con el **mismo ID**  pero con **otro ID** de los que tiene asociado ya

Comment: Disculpa, no he entendido en absoluto tu comentario. Llevo tiempo con bases de datos no relacionales y pues volver ahora de nuevo a mysql me cuesta ponerme en situacion. La segunda parte de tu comentario no se si es buena practica hacer un 3er campo como la concatenacion de los dos anteriores. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira: "En esta tabla no tienes una clave UNIQUE de múltiples campos. Tienes dos claves UNIQUE de un campo cada una.
Para crear un índice de multiples campos, la clave de índice debe contener más de un campo: a varchar(25) NOT NULL, b varchar(2) NOT NULL, UNIQUE `a_b_uidx` (`a`,`b`))" http://www.forosdelweb.com/f86/clave-unica-multiples-campos-1104871/ Proba eso

Comment: podes poner un ejemplo mas claro de datos que queres meter y que no te deja meter?